# Docker fails to build on visual studio 2017 - unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I am using Docker CE 17.09.1 on Win 10 with VS 2017 EE. While trying to build the Docker project, VS is throwing following error. Unfortunately, not able to find any solution via Google. Please help. Thanks.

I logged-in and also tried to build a docker image using CLI but no relief - docker build -t docwebapp .

Contents of docker-compose file -

```
version: '3'

services:   docwebapp:
    image: docwebapp
    build:
      context: .\DocWebApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

[image]

Comment: Are you pushing to a registry (eg. Docker hub)? That would require authentication. Can you post the contents of your docker-compose file?

Comment: @Aetherix - Thanks for your reply. No, I am not publishing my docker image to docker registry. I have updated my question. Please take a look and let me know if there is anything else missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued further with my debugging and saw following code in obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml . This "c:\app" folder was missing and I created it along with giving read\write access to everyone on it. I did not encounter the error when I built the image again

```
labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "C:\\app\\DocWebApp.dll"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "C:\\app"
```